# Java add to int if selected

Tags: java

I have a `checkbox` and an `integer`

```
double total = pear + apple;
```

I want the total to add up by a certain number if `mango` is selected.

```
if(mango.isSelected()) {        
    total + 12;
}
```

I'm getting an unexpected token error though, can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Use `total += 12;`

Answer (score 5):

> *I'm getting an unexpected token error though,*

because doing this  total + 12; is not a valid assignment in java, the value of that operation must go to some variable (in your case to **total** variable)

Do this **total += 12**; you will get the value of total and increment it 12 units..

```
if(mango.isSelected()) {        
    total += 12;
}
```

## Why?

because in java (and almost any modern language) 
total += 12; is the same as `total = total + 12;`
note the assignment...

that was what your code was missing...